# Trouble getting flash object in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash

Is there a way to obtain a flash object reference in chrome the way I can in IE?
The code for IE looks like this:

```
window[appName]
```

and it returns an object that looks like such

```
window[appName] 
{
    saveRecordFnc : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   },
    showMessageFnc : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   },
    saveImageToServerFnc : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   },
    saveTemplateToServerFnc : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   },
    openImageFnc : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   },
    setCanvasDimensionsFnc : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   },
    executeFunction : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   },
    start : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   },
    save : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   },
    exit : function () {      return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));   }
    ...
}
```

window[appName] and document[appName] both return undefined in chrome.  Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
This is the actual tag we use

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="clarkii.swf" width="100%" height="100%" id="myClarkii">
    <param name="movie" value="clarkii.swf" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#333333" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="redirectUrl=saveConfirm.aspx&amp;StartupProject=<%= hdnTempFileName.Value %>&amp;FilePath=<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CarkiiFilePath"] %>&amp;UploadScript=upload.aspx&amp;SnapshotScript=mySnapshot.aspx&amp;DataScript=myUpload_XML.aspx" />
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="<%= Resources.bicweb_resources.GET_ADOBE_FLASH_PLAYER %>" />
    </a>
</object>
```

Comment: if using swfobject to embed, this is handled by their api

Comment: The object is written in the markup of the page using an object tag

Comment: @jedierikb  I tried registering the object with swfobject and I still can't call the saveImageToServerFnc.  The call I tried was swfobject.getObjectById(appName).saveImageToServerFnc();